# Modal popup whit Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony, modal-dialog

In fact my problem is that I want to make a "modal" popup that will look for another twig file.

I mexplique, I have my page "profile", and in my profile page I have a button that directs me to another page "edit", here is an example:

profile:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNBLT.png)

edit:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIgLE.png)

but here after several tries I can not do it. I already created a similar project with "Angular" or I could add the template I wanted but I block it.

here is how I try to do:

profile:

```
> <li>
    <a style="margin-bottom: -47px; margin-left: 100px" class="btn btn-primary"
       href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit') }}"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit">Editer mon profile</a>
</li>
```

edit:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Editer mon Profile</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="span4 offset2 cards">
                    {{ form_start(form, { 'action': path('fos_user_profile_edit'), 'attr': { 'class': 'fos_user_profile_edit' } }) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form) }}
                    <div>
                        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="{{ 'profile.edit.submit'|trans }}" />
                    </div>
                    {{ form_end(form) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

can you help me please?

BOOtstrao.css and JS:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/modal.jss') }}"></script>
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Replace `{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit') }}` from href attribute by `#`

Comment: hello, I tried your method but nothing works ,  j'ai essayé votre methode mais cela ne fonctionne pas

Comment: Have you included bootstrap js and css ?

Comment: yes , i edited my post to show how i was included it

Answer (score 0):

> try to replace `{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit') }}` to `#edit`

Comment: hi , yeah after i did (  href="#edit" ) and (  data-target="#edit" ) and it still does not work ,after i tried to remove "data-target="#edit" and nothing change

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have a profile page and a profile edit form in a modal box on the same page. Please lay back, take a cup of coffee and think. A modal is just a div on a web-page together with all the other html. The only thing is that the modal will be hidden by a css rule, something like `display: none;` and with some javascript the content can be shown. Now one page means **one route** and **one controller-action** that on his turn calls **one twig template**. (that this twig template can include an other (partial) template is something else, the result will still be one html page at the end). In your show-action you will need to generate the edit form too because the form must be placed into the hidden div. ***So instead of having two traditional actions show and edit you will need one action for both.*** Cheers